# Low search for multiple entries by ID?

Tags: low-search

I have a small real estate site and would like to be able to send clients a results shortcut containing specific entries.  Is it possible to  search for multiple entries by entry ID (eg. 54,230,34) with Low Search?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can create a [Low Search Shortcut](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/shortcuts) by creating one in the CP, as [described here](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/shortcuts#save-manually). Then make sure you're setting the `entry_id` parameter to a pipe-separated list, eg. `54|230|34`.

If the order matters, use the `fixed_order` parameter instead.

Then, to display the results, set the `shortcut` parameter on the Results tag to the short name of the shortcut you created, as [described here](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/shortcuts#search-results).